# <permission> only under manifest tag, what it actually means?

Tags: android, permissions, manifest

Recently when I analyses some code, I have found that, there is a permission tag which is just after manifest tag, and not event use under any other tag like activity tag, or receiver tag.

I understand the reason of adding permission tag under some tag like, `<activity>` or `<receiver>`, but does not understand the meaning of using that.

This is something like following:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="3.0" >
<permission android:name="com.mustakim.myproject.permission.READ_ALL" />
</manifest>
```

Can anyone give me any explanation of using something such that?

Comment: Check out this link from android doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

Answer (score 1):

For

```
<permission>
```

From the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

> description: Declares a security permission that can be used to limit access to specific components or features of this or other applications.

Therefore, since you are accessing Android's permissions, you want uses-permission instead since for this node the documentation states:

> Requests a permission that the application must be granted in order for it to operate correctly.

So you use  when making your own permission (such as making a libray that other apps can access, you'd want them do declare use of your library parts), and you use  when your app actually needs a permission it doesn't have normally.

Comment: I also read the documentation from developer guide.
But, there it is said that the permission will be reference in any type of <receiver>, <provider>, <activity> tag, but, in my code, the permission does not reference in any other tag like <application>, <activity> or <receiver> rather then <manifest> tag. Can you inform me is there any meaning of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

The `manifest` element is the correct place for the [`permission` element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html).

Basically, it just *declares* a custom permission. You can then *require* that clients have this permission by referencing it in the `application`, `activity` or `receiver` elements with the [`android:permission`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#prmsn) attribute.

Comment: But, in my code, the permission does not reference in any other tag like <application>, <activity> or <receiver> rather then <manifest> tag. Can you inform me is there any meaning of doing that?

Comment: If you just declare a permission but don't require it, you can remove the permission as unused.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#perms):

> A permission is a restriction limiting access to a part of the code or to data on the device. The limitation is imposed to protect critical data and code that could be misused to distort or damage the user experience.

`<permission>` **[DECLARES](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html)** a security permission.

Once you declare your own permission with this tag, and your app needs access to a feature protected by this permission, you must declare that it uses that permission with `<uses-permission>`, eg:

```
<manifest . . . >
    <permission android:name="com.mustakim.myproject.permission.READ_ALL" . . . />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.mustakim.myproject.permission.READ_ALL" />
    . . .
    <application . . .>
        <activity android:name="com.mustakim.myproject.MyActivity"
              android:name="com.mustakim.myproject.permission.READ_ALL"
              . . . >
        . . .
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

In other words, `<permission>` declares your own permission, and then you use `<uses-permission>` to actually state that your app/activity NEEDS that permission to run.

Check the provided links, there's more details on this there.

Comment: I also read the documentation from developer guide. But, there it is said that the permission will be reference in any type of <receiver>, <provider>, <activity> tag, but, in my code, the permission does not reference in any other tag like <application>, <activity> or <receiver> rather then <manifest> tag. Can you inform me is there any meaning of doing that?

Comment: As @laalto said, if you don't use it anywhere, you can remove it, because there's no point in having it. Also, read Security Tips here: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html